# the validation stopped working

Tags: angular

```
 <form #formAddConfig="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addConfig(formAddConfig)" class="compact" novalidate>
        <clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="openModalAdd" [clrModalStaticBackdrop]="true">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Agregar</h3>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="nameParameter">Nombre Parámetro: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="text" id="nameParameter" name="nameParameter" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="formAddConfig.form.invalid">Agregar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="openModalAdd = false">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </clr-modal></form>
```

---

```
addConfig(formAddConfig: any) { 
       console.log('my form ' ,  formAddConfig.form.controls.nameParameter.value);
  }
```

Everything was working correctly, I was working on the component and I got an error that the value could not be read.

After my account, the form is no longer unoccupied, the save button when the application starts ... (which I used to do before).

It is as if there is a reference, but I do not understand why.

Comment: Please share your TS file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
console.log('my form ' ,  formAddConfig 
  && formAddConfig.form
  && formAddConfig.form.controls
  && formAddConfig.form.controls.nameParameter
  && formAddConfig.form.controls.nameParameter.value
  || 'value is undefined');
```

This will handle all of the undefined errors at once.

Comment: ' my form  value is undefined '

Comment: My button Agregar is activate, BUT I have required

Comment: This means one of your values is undefined, you just have to find which one (with `console.log` of every line)

Comment: the form is broken, I have required but my button is activated

Comment: That's because you have no `[(ngModel)]` in your `input`. You don't have a form if you don't have form controls.